# *Nothing* the god of biomechanics wouldn't let you in heaven for

Tags: grammar

> Roy: I've done questionable things.
>
> Tyrell: Also extraordinary things. Revel in your time!
>
> Roy: **Nothing** the god of biomechanics wouldn't let you in heaven for.

It is from the movie *Blade Runner*. I repeated the last sentence to a native speaker, and he said that it is not grammatically correct — it should be "**There's nothing**," or something like this. Just "**nothing**" does not suffice.

Comment: It's fine in context.

Comment: The sentence is a extension of his prior line ... "I've done nothing the god of biomechanics wouldn't let you in heaven for."

Comment: @StoneyB: Can you explain more. There is no line like you provided in the film.

Comment: @Graduate The statement is implied within the quotation you provided. “I’ve done . . .” is appended during the exchange by “. . . questionable things”, “. . . extraordinary things”, and “. . . nothing the god of biomechanics wouldn’t let you into heaven for.”

Comment: So, Roy is talking about his own deeds that Tyrell's acceptance to heaven depends on... I didn't see it this way.

Comment: @Graduate Not quite. "You" is the generic *you*, like German *man* or French *on*; it is Roy's own justification he speaks of.

Comment: @StoneyB: Everything got very complicated. You may think of writing an exhaustive *answer*. And I have a reason to think thet *you* refers to *Tyrell* because Roy actually kills him after these words.

Comment: Yes, just "nothing" does not suffice – **provided there's nothing else in the dialog**. Consider: _"Nothing like K2 in the Himalayas or anything."_ By itself, that raises more questions than it answers. But let's put that same wording into a larger context: "I hiked up a lot of mountains when I was younger. Some of them were pretty challenging. Nothing like K2 in the Himalayas or anything. But still some pretty challenging hikes, especially in December and January." Now it's just fine. Sure, the passage has some fragments, but **people talk in fragments all the time**. Even @StoneyB sometimes.

Comment: After kissing him ... and in a sense Tyrell himself is the 'god of biomechanics'. Lotsa irony here. But that's all LitCrit and off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of [elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision): a process of omission of words which are to be inferred by the listener. Elision happens in many languages, and follows certain patterns.

For instance, in English, as in many languages, a brief answer is possible, like this:

> Q: Where did you go?
>
> A1: To the park. [Subject and verb are elided.]
>
> A2: ? Park. [Possible, but less usual, and creates an abrupt sense. Perhaps the speaker is out of breath, or indicating an emotional state of being disinclined to conversation.]
>
> Q: What did you have for dinner?
>
> A: Pizza. [A one-word answer to a "what" question is not unusual, and not considered abrupt. "Steak" is the direct object of the elided sentence "I had steak for dinner", where there are no prepositions on the word.]

In the sentence:

> Nothing the god of biomechanics wouldn't let you in heaven for.

words are elided from the hypothetical sentence "**They (= those things that I did) were** nothing the god of biomechanics wouldn't let you in heaven for."

By the way, a better preposition in this type of sentence, at least in a more formal setting, would be "into". If there is no complement for the preposition, it is just "in":

> Let me { in | *into }.

But with a complement like "building":

> Let me { in | into } the building.

Using "in" for "into" is acceptable, but at the cost of contributing to an informal, conversational tone to the sentence (which is obviously appropriate in the context here). This view is probably due to the the bias arising from everyone having had it drilled into their heads in elementary school that "into" should be preferred.

In any case, that would be the only nitpick I could possibly have with the sentence; not its elided subject and verb. :)

Comment: The last peice -- who does *you* in the last sentence refer to: Tyrell, Roy (himself), or any person (may say *a man* instead)?

Comment: @Graduate It has the same meaning as "one"; nothing the god of biomechanics wouldn't let one in heaven for.

Answer (score 1):

The line is not a complete, grammatically correct sentence. It has no subject.

That said, we very often make statements, especially in casual speech, that are not complete, grammatically correct sentences. Like:

"Where are you going?"

"The store."

"The store" is not a complete sentence. It has no subject and no verb, just an object. But the meaning in context is clear. The speaker meant, "I am going to the store." In conversation we often leave out parts of sentences that would just be repetitions of what we or someone else just said.

If you are writing a paper for English class, you probably should limit yourself to complete sentences. Everywhere else, it's not necessarily a requirement.

BTW, reminds me: When I was in elementary school, it was common for teachers to say that when we were taking a test, all of our answers must be complete sentences, and must rephrase the question as a declarative. So for example if there was a question on a test that said, "What is the capital of the United Kingdom?", if a student wrote "London" this would be marked wrong or have points taken off. The student was expected to write, "The capital of the United Kingdom is London." I always thought that was a dumb rule at the time. You know what you asked. Why do I need to repeat it?

My chemistry teacher once said that this was not necessary on his tests. He said, "If I ask a question like, 'How much heat is produced when we mix chemicals A and B?', it's not necessary for you to write, 'Yes indeed, heat is produced when we mix chemicals A and B.' Just write the number."

Comment: Anything about the original situation?

Comment: Wasn't my answer clear? Maybe I should have used your quote rather than making up a new one for my example. "Nothing the god of ..." is not a complete sentence because it has no subject. To make it a complete sentence, you would have to say, "There is nothing ..." or "That is not a thing that ..." But making a statement that is not a complete sentence is not necessarily wrong. It's fine, especially in casual conversation, when the missing parts of the sentence are obvious from context.